# S3 Bucket File Upload Format Changes

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, http-post, image-formats

Im trying to upload file to S3 bucket. It works pretty fine when I upload it from localhost. However when I publish it and use that address it again uploads file but could not recognize format. Im trying to upload image. I think file type changes on the road =). Do you know any way to solve it.

When I upload from localhost images txt equivalant starts with

ÿØÿâICC_PROFILE   lcms  mntrRGB XYZ Ü    ) 9acspAPPL

When I upload it from S3 address

xxx./Prod/api/S3Bucket/AddSimpleFile/abcdesfghi/denemeisim45 it starts with

����ICC_PROFILE   lcms  mntrRGB XYZ �    ) 9acspAPPL

I think something changes the data of image file thus it couldnt read it as jpeg. What other data should I add when I post image to server

Im using this code snippet when sending to server

```
byte[] result;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            result = client.UploadFile(address, filePath);
        }
```

Comment: Looks to me like an encoding issue so it might be worth trying to set encoding to `Encoding.UTF8` and adding content-type `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

Comment: unfortunately didnt work =(